# Using JQuery to create a new "Scope" for Editor

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an educational website, where instructors can create math/science questions, and a student can answer those questions using a gui equation editor (All current web equation editors that I've seen require the knowledge of latex).

Rules that I have written so far:

- Clicking on a space moves the cursor there.
- Clicking a button adds a symbol at the current cursor position.
- Typing numbers adds a dynamically resizing number box to the equation.
- Typing letters adds a letter (variable) to the equation.
- Backspace, delete, and the left/right arrow keys work as expected.
- If you are next to a letter, or number, clicking the up/down arrows steps you into that textbox, so that you can edit it.

My problem:

I'd like to implement things like fractions, and square roots where I could add mini-equation editors within the larger equation editor, and step into these new "scopes" with the up/down arrows much like the textboxes currently.

I am having trouble deciding how to keep the same behavior, but just shrink everything. I would need to resize all of the pictures, containers, and cursor.

I know this question may seem unclear, I'm just really stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I see where you're going here, so I'm going to take a stab at it.

If you haven't already, I would turn your equation editor into a [jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and then use the [jQueryUI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to display the "scopes" or other instances of your plugin. What it sounds like to me is you would like to be able to create an equation in an editor, and perhaps pass the output from that equation to a parent equation editor. I hope that helps. If you can provide some pseudo code I could probably help you further.